# Why doesn't the notification URI work for a MergeCursor?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, android-cursor, android-cursorloader

Suppose you have a `CONTENT_URI` inside your `ContentProvider` in which you want to do some complex stuff and return a combination of Cursors (`MergeCursor`) instead of a simple, single `Cursor`.

It so happens that if you set the notification `URI` on the `MergeCursor` instead of a cursor from within that `MergeCursor`, the notification is not going to work.

Initial code:

```
            Cursor[] cursors = { extraCursorBefore, usersCursor, extraCursorAfter };
            Cursor extendedCursor = new MergeCursor(cursors);
            // Make sure that potential listeners are getting notified
            extendedCursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), CONTENT_URI_PEOPLE);
            return extendedCursor;
```

PS: If by any means, somebody has another idea, or figures out why the hell this didn't work on the original `MergeCursor`, then please, share your knowledge.

Comment: I assume you saw this bug report:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38599

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to set the notification `URI` on a `Cursor` from within the resulting `MergeCursor`.

Code that actually works:

```
            Cursor[] cursors = { extraCursorBefore, usersCursor, extraCursorAfter };
            Cursor extendedCursor = new MergeCursor(cursors);
            // Make sure that potential listeners are getting notified
            usersCursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), CONTENT_URI_PEOPLE);
            return extendedCursor;
```